# Trying to understand dynamic SQL syntax more

Tags: sql-server, dynamic-sql

If I end my query with this:

```
  +'SELECT 
    CPS.CalculatedFromText, 
    CPS.TreatmentOrdinal,
    CPS.ProductID, 
    CPS.OptimizationGroupID,
    CPS.CountCalculatedFromText,
    CPS.CountCalculatedFromText/T.AllCalculatedFromText AS PercentCalculatedFromText,
    CPS.CurrencyCode,
    CPS.Origin,
    CPS.Destination,'+
    case when @passangers='Y' then 'CPS.Passangersgroup'
    when @fareclass='Y' then 'CPS.Fareclass'
    when @ispriorbooking='Y' then 'CPS.IsPriorBooking'
    else '' end +'
INTO ##PercentCalculatedFromText
FROM ##CountCalculatedFromText AS CPS
    INNER JOIN ##AllCalculatedFromText T ON T.ProductID = CPS.ProductID
        AND T.OptimizationGroupID = CPS.OptimizationGroupID
        AND T.CurrencyCode = CPS.CurrencyCode
        AND T.Origin=CPS.Origin
        AND T.Destination=CPS.Destination,'+
    case when @passangers='Y' then ' AND T.Passangersgroup=CPS.Passangersgroup'
    when @fareclass='Y' then 'AND T.Fareclass=CPS.Fareclass'
    when @ispriorbooking='Y' then 'AND T.IsPriorBooking=CPS.IsPriorBooking'
    else '' end

exec (@SQL2)
```

it doesnt work, comes with incorrect syntax near '.' but this:

```
+' SELECT 
    ProductID, 
    OptimizationGroupID,
    SUM(CountCalculatedFromText) AS AllCalculatedFromText,
    CurrencyCode,
    Origin,
    Destination,'+
    case when @passangers='Y' then 'Passangersgroup'
    when @fareclass='Y' then 'Fareclass'
    when @ispriorbooking='Y' then 'IsPriorBooking'
    else '' end +'
INTO ##AllCalculatedFromText
FROM ##CountCalculatedFromText AS cps2
GROUP BY ProductID,
    OptimizationGroupID,
    CurrencyCode,
    Origin,
    Destination,'+
    case when @passangers='Y' then 'Passangersgroup'
    when @fareclass='Y' then 'Fareclass'
    when @ispriorbooking='Y' then 'IsPriorBooking'
    else ''
end
exec (@SQL2)
```

WORKED (all I did was move exec statement above the first set of code)

I am not understanding how I am getting something wrong here.

Further questions: Can you run an exec statement if the dynamic sql code ends with a '?

What do you do when you might end with something like:

```
case when @passangers='Y' then 'Passangersgroup'
    when @fareclass='Y' then 'Fareclass'
    when @ispriorbooking='Y' then 'IsPriorBooking'
    else '' 
+
'variable X'
```

SQL SERVER 2014

Comment: What is the length of variable @SQL2? It could be that the generated statement is being truncated when assigned to the variable.

Comment: declare @SQL2 varchar(max)

Answer (score 0):

You have extra `comma` in `Join` condition in first query

```
........
'INNER JOIN ##AllCalculatedFromText T ON T.ProductID = CPS.ProductID
        AND T.OptimizationGroupID = CPS.OptimizationGroupID
        AND T.CurrencyCode = CPS.CurrencyCode
        AND T.Origin=CPS.Origin
        AND T.Destination=CPS.Destination' + --here
 case when @passangers='Y' then ' AND T.Passangersgroup=CPS.Passangersgroup'
.........
```

Comment: yea, I had forgotten to take that out when I posted it. It is weird since even if I just put +'SELECT 
 CPS.CalculatedFromText
 INTO ##PercentCalculatedFromText
FROM ##CountCalculatedFromText AS CPS'
exec (@SQL2)  it doesnt work..  I declare sql2 declare @SQL2 varchar(max)

Comment: You need to show what you are appending before `+'SELECT CPS.CalculatedFro..`

Answer (score 0):

You've also got a space at the beginning of the string in the second case.  That could seriously alter what happens depending on how the string it's being appended to ends.  If it ends with a new line, it won't make a difference, but if it ends with the last character of the previous command or 'END', you'll end up with 'ENDSELECT' vs. 'END SELECT' which will behave very differently.

Comment: eh? where?  on case when @passangers='Y' then 'Passangersgroup'
    when @fareclass='Y' then 'Fareclass'
    when @ispriorbooking='Y' then 'IsPriorBooking'
    else '' 
+
'variable X'

Comment: Right at the beginning before the SELECT, but you have the same issue in that part as well--variable X will not be separated with whitespace from the part of the query before that.  In this part, quotation marks are part of the syntax to build the string, not part of the string or part of what actuall gets run by exec.

Comment: You should print the string before you exec it when you are debugging so you can see simple whitespace and punctuation errors like the ones you have here.